# JQuery addClass on scroll doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

I have 4 buttons next to each other. What I want is when I scroll to a certain point, the 4 buttons height and width change. The button consists of 2 divs on each other so you can see only one div. When the mouse enter div, the bottom div goes up so you can see both of them. My problem is that if I scroll to that certain point, only the bottom div's attributes change, but the top div stays the same.

HTML

```
        <div class="buttons" class="container">
            <div class="button">
                <div class="topdiv">Something</div>
                <div class="bottomdiv"><p>S.</p></div>
            </div>

            <div class="button" >
                <div class="topdiv">Something</div>
                <div class="bottomdiv"><p>S.</p></div>
            </div>

            <div class="button" >
                <div class="topdiv">Something</div>
                <div class="bottomdiv"><p>S.</p></div>
            </div>

            <div class="button" >
                <div class="topdiv">Something</div>
                <div class="bottomdiv"><p>S.</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery

```
        if (scrollPos < somepoint){
            $(".buttons").removeClass("fixedtop");
            $(".button").removeClass("shrink");
            $(".button div").removeClass("shrink");
            }

        if (scrollPos >= somepoint){
            $(".buttons").addClass("fixedtop");
            $(".button").addClass("shrink");
            $(".button div").addClass("shrink");
            }
```

CSS

```
.button .shrink{
transition: 0.5s;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}  

.button div .shrink{
transition:0.5s;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

The ".button div" works fine, but the ".button" doesn't. I tried it with CSS :hover transition and it worked there, but I can't make it shrink when I scroll to that point in CSS.

Comment: Can you give a live example? The code isn't complete.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250325/show-hide-div-on-scroll

Comment: Well you can see it here: http://proba2.slimless.hu/ujra.html You click Tovább! and scroll until you reach the top of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't quite understand how styles are applied. For example `.button .shrink` will not be applied to `<div class='button shrink'>`, but to the second div in the following pair `<div class='button'><div class='shrink'>`.

In the same way `.button div .shrink` will look for an element with class `shrink` inside a div, and this div should be a child of an element of class 'button'. You don't have an element which satisfies these conditions so your styles are not applied to anything. Try using `.button_shrink` instead of `.button .shrink`  and `.button div.shrink` instead of `.button div .shrink` (you'll need to change `$(".button").addClass("shrink");` to `$(".button").addClass("button_shrink");`).

Illustration of what I'm trying to say:

```css
   
.button .shrink{
color:red;
}  

.button div .shrink{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='button shrink'>
  No styles will be applied to this div
  <div class='shrink'>
    This one is red, because it's 'shrink' inside 'button'
    <div class='shrink'>
      This is blue because it's 'shrink' inside a div which is inside 'button'
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I think you're trying to do:

```css
.button_shrink{
    color:red;
    } 

.button div.shrink{
    color:blue;
    }
```

```html
 <div class='button button_shrink'>
      Red
      <div class='shrink'>
        Blue
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The ".button div .shrink" did work, the ".button .shrink" didn't. Maybe I really don't understand how styles applied, I just started learning it. By the way I tried what you recommended but neither of them are working now. As is mentioned I tried it inside of the CSS file like this and it worked so I thought there's nothing wrong with the CSS:
.button:hover{
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.button:hover .bottomdiv {
  transition:0.5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

Comment: @hashtagslam try to make a small example in jsfiddle which would represent the problem. Also you can play with styles there to see how they work. Your ".button div .shrink" and ".button .shrink" are  identical, it's ".button .shrink" what you see applied, but not there you expect it to be. Add different backgrounds to them and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thank you Nadia, I'm starting to understand it. Your illustration helped me.

Comment: Glad to help! Selectors are a bit confusing when you start to work with them.