# Can anyone help me how to show div when i scroll down?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```html
<div class="col-md-12 fixed-product-bar">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(window).fixed - product - bar(function() {
      $(this).fixed - product - bar({
        'opacity': '1'
      }, 900);
    }

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250325/show-hide-div-on-scroll

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do. With only the title i would say you want a fixed div. position: fixed .

Comment: i edited the post again now you can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery scroll event

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= 400) {
    $('.fixed-product-bar')
    .show()
    .css({
      'opacity': 1,
      //property: value
    });
  }
  else {
    $('.fixed-product-bar')
    .hide()
    .css({
      'opacity': 0,
      //property: value
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body{
height: 1000px;
}
.fixed-product-bar{
display: none;
opacity: 0,
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed-product-bar">
 <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't works, i wanted to show when scroll 900 or above.

Comment: @TouseefAkhtar I've updated my jquery code added an if condition, just change the value coz I've used 400 as an example

Comment: and when i scroll up it will hide.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know about JS, i just tried from my self :(

Comment: is the content of `fixed-product-bar` youre trying to show?

Comment: just copy and paste my jquery code on your file I've updated now the selector, I think that should work on you're end make sure you have jquery library in order to make it work.

Comment: did you add jquery library inside head tag? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>