# Popover doesn't stay, and position stays while page scrolls (Angular 4+)

Tags: html, css, angular, popover

When I click on an icon, a popover shows. 
I realize that there is delay set with the popover, but when I scroll, the popover moves as well.
How can I make it stay where the icon is and not work with scroll?

```
<md-badge class="current-plan-type__icon--badge" direction="right" [mdPopover]="tootltipTemplate" delay="10000"
popoverTrigger="MouseEnter">
 <i class="cui-icon icon icon-info_16 current-plan-type__icon--info"></i>
</md-badge>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/) so it would be easier to help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250325/show-hide-div-on-scroll <--the best answer but how do you do it Typescript (Angular 4+)?

Comment: did you try by using the option data-container="body" or [container] ="body" ?? if it is not the problem another solution is moving out your popover element to the root div element in the templat or, just moving out of the scroll div.

Comment: yes so I am not using boostrap, I am using another library

Answer (score 0):

Just move tootltipTemplate outside of your scrolleable div it will be called even if is not at the same level.

I think you have this problem: the popover template inside of the scrolleable div.

```
<div #root>
   <div #scrolleable>
       <div #tootltipTemplate></div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Then my suggetion is: moving out the popover template of the crolleable div.

```
<div #root>
   <div #scrolleable>       
   </div> 
   <div #tootltipTemplate></div>
</div>
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: That didn't work, I need an answer like this but for typescript: stackoverflow.com/questions/13250325/show-hide-div-on-scroll